# What does the symbol "%<>%" do in R?

Tags: r, operators, magrittr

I see this symbol: `%<>%`,  in someone's R code and could not find out what it does by googling. Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Comment: It's in the magrittr package.  `library(magrittr); help(\`%<>%\`)`

Comment: thank you @RichardScriven!!!

Answer (score 1):

Functions surrounded by percent symbols such as `%<>%`, `%in%`, `%over%`, `%*%`, etc. are called [infix operators](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Infix-and-prefix-operators) and, as pointed out by @RichardScriven, can be found in the manual by surrounding them with backticks or quotation marks: `?"%<>%"` or `` ?`%<>%` `` should both bring you to the help pages ([GitHub version here](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/blob/master/man/tee.Rd); [here's](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/blob/master/R/pipe.R) the source code)

You can define your own *a la*:

```
"%+%" <- function(s1, s2) paste0(s1, s2)
"%U%" <- function(A, B) union(A, B)
```

And so on. [Here's the relevant chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) in Hadley Wickham's book.